# MySQL Fix Gap in Ordinal Sequence

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.5, ordinals

all.  I'm working on an assignment to update the order images appear in a table.  This is done with a table structure that looks like: product_key, image_key, image_order.  The first two are foreign keys to other tables and the latter is an ordinal sequence in which the images will appear.  In the process of selecting the images, I matched those available to a set of rules.  In some cases there was no image that fit a criteria set leading to a gap in the image order.  E.g.,

| product_key | image_key | image_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5692 | 42265 | 0 |
| 5692 | 42207 | 1 |
| 5692 | 42210 | 2 |
| 5692 | 42212 | 3 |
| 5692 | 42266 | 5 |
| 5692 | 42273 | 6 |
| 5692 | 42268 | 7 |
| 5692 | 42264 | 8 |

This is an example for a single product_key but there are over 1200 product_keys and over 11k total rows.  What I need to do is find a place where row(n) product_key equals row(n-1) product_key but row(n) image_order does not equal row(n-1) image_order+1 and then change row(n) image order to row(n-1) image_order+1.

Based on an example from someone who no longer works here, I tried this:

```
UPDATE mytable i
    JOIN (
        SELECT ordered_id, product_key, image_order, 
            (@ROW:=(IF(@productkey=product_key, @ROW+1, 0))) AS row_order, 
            (@productkey:=product_key) AS pid 
            FROM mytable,
                (SELECT @ROW=-1, @productkey:=-1) a 
                ORDER BY product_key, image_order) b 
            ON b.ordered_id=i.ordered_id
        SET i.image_order = b.row_order
        WHERE i.image_order <> b.row_order;
```

But that updated image_order to 0 in all rows due to some difference between when he developed it to when I ran it.

I am looking at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523002/insert-ordinal-number) and I feel like it's close to what I need, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Here's the [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=0c22568c79d6b1b04fdabe5771245c08) for the problem.

Any thoughts on how to cover those gaps so the final display doesn't have gaps?

TIA

Comment: Added `mysql5.7` because with 8+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: Feel free to add info to this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3ec11c3fe68e9765fd21a71735fafca8) to make your question a reproducible  (as in [mre])

Comment: Thanks, @Luuk!  I added a correct DBFIDDLE and updated the tag to properly reference MariaDB 10.5.

Comment: MariaDB 1.5 has ROW_NUMBER() too, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f5949f99e28f153a95f761ac9b88e7ac   (which can make your UPDATE simpler, but that's left for you (

Comment: Okay, I see that.  I see I haven't explained the problem as well as I might.  What I posted was the set for one product_key, but there are over 1200 product keys in the table and over 11k total rows in the table.  This has R be sequential over the full data set where it needs to reset for each new product_key.

Comment: You need to add a "PARTITION BY product_key". That tells ROW_NUMBER() to reset the counter whenever the product number changes.  One of your [original links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523002/insert-ordinal-number) has an example.  BTW, if you're looking at MySQL examples, be sure to search for ones using v8+, which supports window functions like row_number().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @luuk and @sos!  Here is the solution:

```
insert into mytable_2 
with image_order_update_CTE (ordered_id, product_key, image, image_order, R)
as 
(
SELECT 
   m.*, 
   row_number() over (partition by product_key order by image_order)-1 R 
FROM mytable m
ORDER BY product_key
)
select image_order_update_CTE.ordered_id, image_order_update_CTE.product_key, image_order_update_CTE.image, image_order_update_CTE.image_order, image_order_update_CTE.R from image_order_update_CTE
;
```

I really appreciate this community and thanks again.
VtR